# DNS using blockchain (how can i hashed my domain name ) in the code below help me to complete this code

Tags: web3js, blockchain, truffle, ganache, hash

```
import Web3 from "web3";
import Registry from "./contracts/Registry.json";
import Resolver from "./contracts/Resolver.json";
import Cache from "./contracts/Cache.json";
import trufflemigration from "./contracts/Migrations.json";
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import  "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ web3: null, contracts: {} });

  useEffect(() => {
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545");

    async function template() {
      const web3 = new Web3(provider);
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      const registryDeployedNetwork = Registry.networks[networkId];
      const resolverDeployedNetwork = Resolver.networks[networkId];
      const cacheDeployedNetwork = Cache.networks[networkId];
      const trufflemigrationDeployedNetwork = trufflemigration.networks[networkId];

      const registryContract = new web3.eth.Contract(Registry.abi, registryDeployedNetwork.address);
      const resolverContract = new web3.eth.Contract(Resolver.abi, resolverDeployedNetwork.address);
      const cacheContract = new web3.eth.Contract(Cache.abi, cacheDeployedNetwork.address);
      const trufflemigrationContract = new web3.eth.Contract(trufflemigration.abi, trufflemigrationDeployedNetwork.address);

      setState({
        web3: web3,
        contracts: {
          registry: registryContract,
          resolver: resolverContract,
          cache: cacheContract,
          trufflemigration: trufflemigrationContract
        }
      });

      // To interact with smart contracts, you require the API and contract address.
    }

    provider && template();
  }, []);

  console.log(state);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { registry, resolver, cache, trufflemigration } = state.contracts;

    async function writeData1() {
      const data = await registry.methods.updateIp( string message  ,uint256 value   ).send({ from: "0xD21ffdb9136E67B4bF6bd18f9Fb915A87e47e16c" });
      console.log(data);
    }

    async function writeData2() {
      const data = await registry.methods.register( string message   ,   uint256 value  ).send({ from: "0xD21ffdb9136E67B4bF6bd18f9Fb915A87e47e16c" });
      console.log(data);
    }



    async function readData1() {
      const data = await resolver.methods.resolve().call();
      console.log(data);
    }

    async function readData2() {
      const data = await cache.methods.resolve().call();
      console.log(data);
    }

    async function writeData3() {
      const data = await cache.methods.updateCache( bytes32 indexed nameHash  , bytes ip  ).send({ from: "0xA64C7c25153Bece2ad692731a0b61858F64808c2 " });
      console.log(data);
    }

    async function readData3() {
      const data = await trufflemigration.methods.setCompleted().call();
      console.log(data);
    }

    async function readData4() {
      const data = await trufflemigration.methods.setCompleted().call();
      console.log(data);
    }

    registry && writeData1();
    registry && writeData2();
    resolver && readData1();
    cache && readData2();
    cache && writeData3();
    trufflemigration && readData3();
    trufflemigration && readData4();
  }, [
    state.contracts,
    state.contracts.registry,
    state.contracts.resolver,
    state.contracts.cache,
    state.contracts.trufflemigration
  ]);
   
  return (
    <div className="App"></div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: this my graduation project, i am really need help